# Where do I load route data in Angular2

Tags: http, typescript, angular

In Angular 1 I would load http data (user profiles, etc) in the resolve. It seemed to me, that was what the resolve was for. Now I have no clear place to do it, but lots of choices.

`@CanActivate()` seems like it can work... but it returns a `boolean` and the name makes it obvious this is the wrong place for http requests.

`ngOnInit` is nice - but it is run after the components constructor. That means I can't do anything with the user data in the constructor like bind it to member variables or anything. Sure, I could do that in `ngOnInit` too but doesn't that seem like it should go in the constructor?

`constructor()` is then an obvious candidate. But http reqs can be long and they themselves don't seem to actually have anything to do with constructing the component.

I think it should be more like:

`gatherData() -> constructor() -> ngOnInit()`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `constructor()` to setup Dependency Injection and not much else. `ngOnInit()` is better place to "start" - it's where/when components' bindings are resolved, so you can use the data passed from parent component. For components used in routing you also have `routerOnActivate()`. Here's the simple example of lifecycle hooks for a route component:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/test', name: 'Test', component: Dummy },
])
class Main {}

@Component({ template: `` })
export class Dummy {
  constructor() { console.log("Dummy: constructor"); }
  ngOnInit() { console.log("Dummy: ngOnInit"); }
  ngAfterContentInit() { console.log("Dummy: ngAfterContentInit"); }
  ngAfterViewInit() { console.log("Dummy: ngAfterViewInit"); }
  ngOnDestroy() { console.log("Dummy: ngOnDestroy"); }
  routerOnActivate() { console.log("Dummy: routerOnActivate"); }
  routerOnDeactivate() { console.log("Dummy: routerOnDeactivate"); }
}

// output:
Dummy: constructor
Dummy: routerOnActivate
Dummy: ngOnInit
Dummy: ngAfterContentInit
Dummy: ngAfterViewInit
....
Dummy: routerOnDeactivate
Dummy: ngOnDestroy
```

Depending on what you need, you can call services and setup subscriptions in any of these hooks. If you need router data use `routerOnActivate()`, if you need input bindings use `ngOnInit()` etc...